# Why is no string output with 'echo %var%' after using 'set var = text' command in cmd?

Tags: batch-file, cmd, environment-variables

I set a variable in cmd with the `set` command, and tried to `echo` it.

Here is an example:

```bat
C:\Users\Logan>set var = text

C:\Users\Logan>set var
var = text

C:\Users\Logan>echo %var%
%var%

C:\Users\Logan>
```

Is there a way to force the cmd to `echo` the variable and not the raw text?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You need to remove whitespace before and after `=`:

```
set "var=text"
echo %var%
text
```

Comment: Ok, it works, but why? Could you also use `set /p` with this?

Comment: @Logern When you do `set var = text` you are actually creating a variable named `var ` (notice the space after the r).

Answer (score 27):

### Assigning a value/string to an environment variable

It is best to use following syntax with command extensions enabled to define or modify an environment variable:

```
set "var=text"
```

The command is **set** and the parameter is `"variable=value"`.

The parameter string can be enclosed in double quotes as on all commands as long as command extensions are enabled as by default.

If the double quotes are not used around `variable=value`, command **set** interprets everything to end of line after the first equal sign including not visible spaces and horizontal tabs at end of line as string value to assign to the variable.

The name of the variable starts with first non whitespace character (after double quote if used) and ends left to first equal sign. The value assigned to the variable starts right of first equal sign and ends at end of line or last double quote.

```
set VAR = TEXT
```

The command line above creates an environment variable with name **VAR**<kbd>Space</kbd> and assigns the string <kbd>Space</kbd>**TEXT** to this variable.

The usage of

```
set var="text"
```

is often not correct as this results in assigning to variable `var` the text with the quotes included and all trailing spaces and tabs. Referencing now `var` on another code line with surrounding quotes often results in an error message as the variable holds itself the text already with quotes. For more details see the answer on [How to set environment variables with spaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34402887/3074564)

Example:

```
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion
set "var=text"
set "var = text"
set "var1=and more text"
set var2="and more text"
set var3="text with 1 trailing space" 
set var
echo var3=%var3%^<- Do you see the trailing space?
echo/
set UnwantedSpaceVar=Hello 
echo %UnwantedSpaceVar%! ^<- Where does the space come from?
echo/
echo There is a trailing space after Hello in this code snippet.
echo/
set "TrailingSpacesIgnored=Hi"   
echo %TrailingSpacesIgnored%! ^<- The 3 trailing spaces above are ignored.
echo/
endlocal
pause
```

Running this small batch code results in the output:

```
var=text
var = text
var1=and more text
var2="and more text"
var3="text with 1 trailing space" 
var3="text with 1 trailing space" <- Do you see the trailing space?

Hello ! <- Where does the space come from?

There is a trailing space after Hello in this code snippet.

Hi! <- The 3 trailing spaces above are ignored.
```

Enclosing `variable=value` in quotes can be done even if the text itself contains 1 or more double quotes.

```
set "Quote=""
```

This line defines the variable `Quote` with the value `"`. Command **set** interprets everything after first equal sign left to last double quote as value to assign to variable with name between the first quote and first equal sign.

**Note:** A string value with `"` inside and next `&` or `&&` or `||` can be even on usage of `set "variable=value"` misinterpreted and so result in unexpected behavior as it can be seen on running a batch file with following two lines:

```
@echo off
set "Variable=Value with one double quote in the middle" & echo Oh, there is something wrong here!"
```

`Value with one double quote in the middle" & echo Oh, there is something wrong here!` is the string to assign to the environment variable, but assigned to the variable is just `Value with one double quote in the middle` and the rest of the line after `"` in the middle and after `&` interpreted as conditional operator and not literally is interpreted as additional command to execute by `cmd.exe`. The same problem exists with `&&` or `||` after a `"` with 0 or more spaces/tabs between. This problem is not caused by command **set**. It is caused by Windows command processor which splits the line up into a command line with **set** and one more command line with **echo** with [conditional execution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564) of the **echo** command line.

### Variable assignment with disabled command extensions

The command syntax `set "variable=value"` cannot be used if the command extensions are disabled with `setlocal DisableExtensions` in the batch file (or in Windows registry which is very uncommon and never seen by me on any Windows computer). A syntax error would be the result on execution of the batch file.

It is only possible to use `set variable=value` with command extensions disabled whereby the value can contain also double quotes and care must be taken on trailing spaces/tabs as they are also assigned to the environment variable.

Run in a command prompt window `cmd /?` and `setlocal /?` for more information about command extensions and which commands are affected by command extensions. Note: The output list of affected commands misses **exit** as described in answers on [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37515901/)

### Variable assignment via arithmetic expression

Using command **set** with option `/A` changes completely the parsing of second argument, i.e. the string after `set /A`. With option `/A` as first argument the second string is interpreted as **arithmetic expression** and being therefore processed completely different than on assigning a string value to an environment variable. Environment variables are always of type string and never of type integer.

The usage of option `/A` requires enabled command extensions as otherwise the command **set** ignores the rest of the line completely without any error message.

It is in most cases not recommended to just assign a number to an environment variable using an arithmetic expression, i.e. using `set /A var=1`. `set "var=1"` or just `set var=1` (and no trailing whitespaces) are a little bit faster because environment variables are always of type string.

In an arithmetic expression whitespaces are interpreted as delimiters for variable names, numbers and operators. For that reason the command line `set /A var = 1` **does not define** a variable with name **VAR**<kbd>Space</kbd> with the string <kbd>Space</kbd>**1** as `set var = 1` does. `set /A var = 1` defines a variable with name **VAR** with string value **1** after converting `1` from string (batch file contains `1` as character with hexadecimal code value 31) to integer with value `1` and back to a string with the two values 0x31 and 0x00 (string terminating null).

### Variable assignment via a prompt

Also using command **set** with option `/P` changes the parsing of the
string after variable name and equal sign. The string after the variable name and the equal sign is interpreted as prompt text to output and not as string to assign to the environment variable.

The environment variable gets assigned the string entered by prompted user (or redirected from a file or command/application), or in case of user does not enter anything before pressing <kbd>RETURN</kbd> or <kbd>ENTER</kbd>, keeps its current value respectively is still undefined if not defined before the prompt.

The usage of option `/P` requires enabled command extensions as otherwise the command **set** ignores the rest of the line completely without any error message.

Most used syntax for prompting a user for a string is:

```
set /P var="Please enter something: "
```

The command **set** removes in this case automatically the double quotes around the prompt text before printing to handle **STDOUT** (console window if not redirected).

But working is also:

```
set /P "var=Please enter something: "
```

Please read [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39835318/3074564) for more details about prompt text parsing and how to output a prompt text with surrounding double quotes.

Comment: 1. For the syntax `set "VAR=Text"` you should mention that this only works in case command extensions are enabled (see also `cmd /?` and `setlocal /?`). 2. For `set /P`, the best syntax is actually `set /P VAR="Please enter something: "`, because in case the prompt text begins with quotes on its own, the syntax `set /P "VAR=" is prohibited: "` might lead to unexpected results, while `set /P VAR="" is prohibited: "` does not.